# SSO Django. Центр общей авторизации\аутентификации

Tags: python, django, авторизация, аутентификация

Доброго времени суток.
Делаю сайт на Django и столкнулся со следующей задачей.

**Есть:** 2 независимых сайта-части с.

**Нужно:** реализовать общею авторизацию/авторизацию через example0.com (тоже реализован мной). Сделать что-то на подобие Google и Youtube. Учитывать возможность размещения сайтов на разных доменах.

На example0.com - основная информация о пользователе (ник, имя, группы)

На example1.com и example2.com - дополнительные данные о юзере, специфичные для конкретного сайта соответственно.

**При входе**, если юзер уже вошел на одном из сайтов - автоматом вход на остальные (если нет прав - просто Permission denide; не вошел - перенаправить на LogIn на example0.com - при успешном входе - перенаправление на точку входа).

Если открыты 2 вкладки с разными сайтами, и на одной произошел **LogOut** - то на второй тоже должен произойти "выход".

Есть какие-то рекомендации как это реализовать? Возможно посоветуйте уже готовые модули, что бы самому не писать велосипед.

Comment: Если бы домен был один, а сайты как поддомены, как на СО, то можно было бы поиграть с куки и сессиями. А так вам только OAuth какой прикручивать, межсайтовое взаимодействие обычно сильно затруднено

Comment: @FeroxTL Хорошо, как реализовать, если на одном домене? Если не трудно, с каким-то примером.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас всё на одном домене, а сайты представляют собой поддомены (так же, как реализовано на СО) то давайте последовательно разбирать все случаи.

По умолчанию куки отправляются только по точному соответствию. Чтобы позволить поддоменам читать куки друг друга можно добавить точку перед названием куки - это установит её на весь домен и все поддомены (`.mydomain.com`,  [RFC 2109](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109)).

Однако современные браузеры следуют более новому [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) и игнорируют все точки в начале, что означает, что все куки с основного домена доступны на поддоменах. (Однако я всё же советую следовать 2109)

Поэтому достаточно устанавливать cookie на поддомене и они будут доступны на всех доменах и поддоменах:

```
Set-Cookie: name=value; domain=.mydomain.com
```

Теперь посмотрим что мы можем сделать в django. Выставляем следующие настройки:

```
# cookie для сессии будут выставляться глобально на все поддомены
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".example.com"
# название сессионной переменной, чтобы не было конфликтов
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = "anycookiename"
# секретный ключ django, его надо просто установить одинаковым для всех сайтов
SECRET_KEY="anykey"
```

Так можно добиться авторизации сразу на всех сайтах - авторизовавшись на одном, получаем авторизацию на всех остальных.

Не совсем то, что нам нужно. Теперь надо поиграть с cookie и сессиями. Тут нужно понять, что наша задача сводится к получению сессии, в которой можно хранить что угодно, в которой в том числе хранится id авторизованного пользователя (по-моему в джанго эта переменная называется `_auth_user`)

Приведу пример с реально работающего сайта. Сам сайт находился на основном домене (example.com), был центр авторизации (auth.example.com) и второй сайт на поддомене (new_site.example.com). Базы для данных сайтов использовались разные - на auth.example.com была полная база всех зарегистрированных пользователей, на двух остальных она пополнялась по мере регистрации на основных. При заходе на сайт, на котором ты ещё не зарегистрирован, можно было определить зарегистрирован ли ты в центре ваторизации (ну и соответственно на другом сайте). Небольшой пример - реализована middleware, которая на каждый запрос проверяет вошёл ли пользователь на каком-либо из других сайтов (по факту просто запрос просто проксировался с теми же cookies) - этим занимается cookie `fjLogged` (она должна выставляться вручную). `user_not_registered` вставляется когда пользователь вообще нигде не авторизовывался. Ну и при авторизации на любом из сайтов при наличии данного пользователя в базе он также авторизовывался и на этом сайте:

```
class FJAuthenticationMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        if not settings.DEBUG:
            if not request.user.is_authenticated() and \
                    'fjLogged' in request.COOKIES and \
                    not request.session.get('user_not_registered'):
                # Белый список имён функций, в которых происходит авторизация, нужно, чтобы не было было зацикливания на этой функции
                if view_func.__name__ in [
                    'auth',
                    'fj_complete',
                ]:
                    return None

                resp = requests.get(cls.ACCOUNT_URL, cookies=request.COOKIES).json()
                if 'login' in resp and BaseUser.objects.filter(login=resp['login']).exists():
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('social:begin', args=[FJOAuth2.name]))
                else:
                    request.session['user_not_registered'] = True
            elif request.user.is_authenticated() and 'fjLogged' not in request.COOKIES:
                return logout(request, next_page=reverse('index'))
```

Из минусов - на каждый запрос на данном сайте уходил запрос на сайт авторизации. Это добавляло неплохую нагрузку. Это вариант решения "в лоб" - не самый красивый, но рабочий.

Вообще когда всё это разрабатывалось (года 1,5 назад) нам ничего не подошло из сторонних решений. Беглый поиск сейчас тоже ничего не дал.

От себя скажу, что всё это достаточно сложно в реализации.

Есть ещё вариант спроектировать структуру приложения немного иначе, переопределить систему авторизации и манипулируя сессией, авторизовывать человека на том или ином ресурсе - скажем, на первом сайте id пользователя задавать сессионной переменной `_user_auth_site1`, на последующих аналогично. Для подгрузки данных о пользователе настроить несколько подключений к разным бд в джанго. Всё зависит от вашей фантазии.

Вообще если у вас сайты совсем разные и не нужно сразу регистрировать пользователя повсюду или выводить какую-то информацию во время использования одним из сайтов, то советую использовать oauth - там при запросе как раз есть доступ к информации, которую надо запросить при регистрации. Всё вышеприведённое доставляет много боли всем разработчикам, я советую несколько раз подумать прежде чем так делать.

Comment: FeroxTL, можете дать линки на хорошие примеры и туториал для outh??

Comment: @StSan используйте [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth)